# Using liquid with haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, liquid

I'm planning to develop a CMS with ruby/rails. One of the main key features that I'm planning is to give the user to edit their layout (I'm planning to do this through liquid)

meanwhile i have red some good articles on HAML and SaaS. So just wondering whether i can use
haml + liquid + sass for my work

If possible i would thankful if you could point me some resources

thanks in advance

cheers,

sameera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that HAML and Liquid are really compatible. Plus, as HAML has significant whitespace, i don't see it as a good idea to introduce it as the markup for CMS content editing (assuming we are dealing with an average webmaster or a regular user with a WYSIWYG editor here).

Comment: Arturo's answer is the correct one. Using the `==` operator, it is possible to make Haml play nice with Liquid. **If** you wish to add this layer of complexity to your project, it is feasible.

Answer (score 4):

I think that is possible, take a look at this [project mixing Jekyll, Haml and SCSS](https://github.com/rantan/jekyll-haml-scss-sample).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen haml and liquid working at least once on this jekyll fork:

http://github.com/henrik/jekyll

So what you are proposing is certainly possible. I don't know whether it will be "easy", though.